# Rails Postgres: Getting the highest frequency records in login_activity and impressionist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Rails app that uses [login activity](https://github.com/ankane/authtrail) to track user logins and [impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) to track views on different models such as `Product` and `Service`. I am making a dashboard to show the **Users that are most active** (have the most logins) and the **Products and Services that have the most views**.

So in my controller

```
@logins = LoginActivity.group('user_id').order('count_all').count
@products = Impression.group(impressionable_type: 'Product').order('count_all').count
@services = Impression.group(impressionable_type: 'Service').order('count_all').count
```

In my view

```
- @logins.each do |l|
  - @user = User.find_by_id(l)
  = @user.name
- @products.each do |p|
  - @product = Product.find_by_id(p)
  = @product.name
- @services.each do |s|
  - @service = Service.find_by_id(s)
  = @service.name
```

However, I don't know how to **limit the results** to only the top 5 as `.limit(5)` doesn't work. Also, is there a better way to write the query?

Comment: And why limit does not work?

Comment: Model.limit(5) should work, there is no limit in your sample code.